# Custom admin UI grid not showing success or error messages

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.4

I have created a **custom grid** in the admin panel **using UI components**. Everything is working fine except that there is **no success/error message shown on the grid page**.

If I redirect the controller after saving action to the edit record page, it shows the success/error message.

I have also tried to redirect to some other grid after saving the data, and the message is being shown correctly there.

I have matched almost everything of my grid with another working grid, but could not find any clue yet.

Can anyone help me out to find the problem?

Please let me know if you need to see the code.

**Update: Added code below.**

**Grid Controller (Which has problem):**

```
<?php
namespace Stack\RuleBasedDiscount\Controller\Adminhtml\Rules;

class Index extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    const ADMIN_RESOURCE = 'Stack_RuleBasedDiscount::rules';
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    public function __construct(\Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context, \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory) {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $this->_view->loadLayout();
        $this->_setActiveMenu('Stream_RuleBasedDiscount::rules');
        $this->_addBreadcrumb(__('Rule Based Discount'), __('Rule Based Discount'));
        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
        $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend(__('Rule Based Discount'));
        return $resultPage;
    }
}
```

**Save Controller:**

```
<?php

namespace Stack\RuleBasedDiscount\Controller\Adminhtml\Rules;

class Saveedit extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action {

    protected $_ruleModel;
    protected $_storeManager;

    public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context, \Stack\RuleBasedDiscount\Model\Rule $ruleModel, \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
    ) {
        $this->_ruleModel = $ruleModel;
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute() {
        try {
            $data = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
            $this->_ruleModel->setData($data);
            $this->_ruleModel->save();
            $message = __('Rule information has been saved successfully.');
            $this->messageManager->addSuccess($message);
            $this->_redirect('rulebaseddiscount/rules/index');
            return;
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $message = __('There was some problem in saving rule information. Please try again later.');
            $this->messageManager->addError($message);
            $this->_redirect($this->_redirect->getRefererUrl());
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please add your code so we can get easily some idea?

Comment: code For UI grid?

Comment: No . Controller  file in which action are you not able to see messages?

Comment: can you please share your save controller code?

Comment: @MohitKumarArora Please share your  saving action code

Comment: @RutveeSojitra, shared the code.

Comment: @Abdul, shared the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can write :

please try below and check once

$message="There was some problem in saving rule information. Please try again later";

> $this->messageManager->addError(_($message));

or

> $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage($message);

Comment: Already tried that.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
public function execute()
{
    try {
        $data = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
        $this->_ruleModel->setData($data);
        $this->_ruleModel->save();
        $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('Rule information has been saved successfully.'));
        $this->_redirect('*/*/');
        return;
    } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
        $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
        $this->_redirect($this->_redirect->getRefererUrl());
        return;
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $message = __('There was some problem in saving rule information. Please try again later.');
        $this->messageManager->addError($message);
        $this->_redirect($this->_redirect->getRefererUrl());
        return;
    }
    $this->_redirect('*/*/');
    return;
}
```

**OR**

```
public function execute()
{
    if ($data = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue()) {
        try {
            $ruleModel = $this->_objectManager->create('Stack\RuleBasedDiscount\Model\Rule');
            $ruleModel->setData($data);
            $ruleModel->save();
            $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('Rule information has been saved successfully.'));
            $this->_redirect('*/*/');
            return;
        } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
            $this->_redirect('*/*/postAction');
            return;
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $message = __('There was some problem in saving rule information. Please try again later.');
            $this->messageManager->addError($message);
            $this->_redirect('*/*/postAction');
            return;
        }
    }
    $this->_redirect('*/*/');
    return;
}
```

**Note:** Please put your referer url above code for eg. "$this->_redirect('adminhtml/abc/postAction');"

Comment: What is the problem in my code?

Comment: @MohitKumarArora I think your have not added proper redirect action in your code